# How to reuse EF data context when data access method is called from within a loop?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Given data access object `Data` and a method of this data access object with signature `public void GetEntityAttributesValues(int sessId, int entId)` called from a `foreach` loop, what is the best way to reuse the EF data context instead of creating it for each call from the loop?

Loop:

```
foreach (var ord in Data.Entities.Where(m => m.SessionId == CurrentSessionId))
    {
        Data.GetEntityAttributesValues(sid, ord.Id);
        ...
    }
```

Method:

```
    public void GetEntityAttributesValues(int sessId, int entId)
    {
        var tsOptions = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tsOptions))
        {
            using (var context = new MyDataEntities(MyDataConnection))
            {
                var attVals = context.OrderAttributeValues.Where(a => a.SessionId == sessId
                    && a.OrderId == entId).ToList();
                foreach (var attVal in attVals)
                {
                    var att = Attributes.Single(a => a.Key == attVal.AttributeId);
                    AttributeValues[att.Value] = attVal.AttributeValue;
                }
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

So instead of creating a new context within using block every time this methods is called from the loop I would like to reuse the data context...

Comment: Your method signature is very confusing for a 'get' method and without  a `SaveChanges` call `scope.Complete()` is redundant.

Comment: You're right, but that is irrelevant, the question is about data context reuse...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use Data context is using the IoC and Repository pattern together, after setting up the IoC like structure map ( https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap-MVC3 ) you can use the Repository Like this:

```
public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory 
{
    private DatabaseContext _database;
    public DatabaseContext Get() {
        return _database ?? (_database = new DatabaseContext());
    }
    protected override void DisposeCore() {
        if (_database != null)
            _database.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FooRepository : IFooRepository {
    private readonly DatabaseContext _database;
    private readonly IDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
    private readonly IDbSet<Foo> _dbset;
    public MyRepository (IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory) {
        _databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        _database = _database ?? (_database = _databaseFactory.Get());
        _dbset = _database.Set<Foo>();
    }
    protected DatabaseContext Database {
        get { return _database; }
    }
    public virtual void Add(Foo entity) {
        _dbset.Add(entity);
    }
```

}